# Sort records alphabetically from mongodb when data is encrypted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, encryption, data-structures

So basically i have some names stored in my mongo db collection where the data is encrypted using google kms encryption and it is decrypted when user requests that data but the problem here is that i want to apply sorting that is available in mongodb(or any other options if available).
My main options here are:-

1. Save name as a normal string (not possible in my case as the name needs to be encrypted due to security concern)
2. Calculate and store some kind of identifier that acts like a sorting key or hash when inserting the data.
3. Sort the data when user is retrieving the data on node server as it is already decrypted by kms middleware or something(I am not entirely on how that process work). (problem here arise is that we are only getting 40 records at a time so that will result in inconsistencies)

##### What i have thought till now is to calculate a numeric value from the name and store it and run sorting on that. For that the calculation should be alphabetical and consistent which i haven't got yet. (Any Ideas)

So my main question here is how should accomplish this?

Additional info

MongoDB structure(every record have this key where the data is saved in binary format)

```
{first_name:Binary('wy/QGJoo+rVDqoaPia+X+rMwOZlTFBLaxT/WjTHmAOfsdkH4hFO0JdTZFy5CLd2xZdHApZp9tqYNyX+VeZIlrwNZ5KDEVxc1FhFL...', 0)}
```

After retrieving data through google kms we get plain text

```
first_name='Jim'
```

Comment: If you store some indication of name ordering in the database, the security of the encrypted names will be drastically reduced.  Even if the names cannot be decrypted by an untended person/process, under some circumstances, much could be inferred from a known/understood ordering.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes but isn't there any other way?

Comment: The requirements to encrypt names and sort by names seem to be in direct conflict with each other.  If sorting is truly required, you may need to give up some security.